# Custom button: Click through label

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling

I need to create custom `Button` - a `Panel` with 2 `Label`s inside for nice visual formatting.

But I need to click on panel through `Label`s to trigger an `event`, for example, `MouseDown`, or I need to assign that `event` to both labels.

I tried to create `UserControl` but problem is the same - if I set `MouseDown` event to `UserControl`, labels in it prevent to click control itself.

If I set to `Label.Enable = false` it resolves that problem but generate another -  text on `Label` become `gray` and that property I cannot overwrite (I need black text, and red when some `events` occur).

Comment: What's bad to assign same event handler to Click events of all controls?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti that it encourages you to make near endless switch statements that will determine the action executed.

Comment: @TimothyGroote no, because (in this case) you just need to trigger a _click action_ regardless where user effectively clicked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do is to propagate your `MouseDown` `event` in your `Label` to call  `MouseDown` `event` for your `Panel`

```
private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    //Do something here
}

private void label2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    panel1_MouseDown(sender, e);
}
```

To distinguish the `sender` you could leave the `sender` for your `label` event the same (`Label`) - not changing it to `Panel`. Just in case you would need some distinction in the `panel_MouseDown`.

Comment: Damn, you write faster  than me :D

Comment: @Gnqz you wrote the same answer?? :D

Comment: Nitpickng: The way you propagate the `MouseEventArgs` is not quite correct unless the two controls share the same `Location`. If necessary constructing an adjusted `e` will help, although it is a rare case when it matters just __where__ a `Button` is hit. And __what__ to pass as `sender` is also open for debate, but you did mention that..